# Intercept all outgoing connections made by a process to redirect it to a localhost proxy

Tags: transparentproxy

I am working in an environment where there are multiple services hosted.  A service(consider web services) exposes some APIs and also acts as client to call other services too.

Now what I want to achieve is that if Service A (acting as client) wants to talk to Service B(acting as server here) using http , then I want to intercept outgoing HTTP request and redirect it to localhost proxy.

There are multiple services running on a host and a service also talks to multiple other services, so I don't want to change the configuration of every outgoing endpoint configuration to point to proxy.

Sample configurations:

Following are the services endpoint which service A connects while doing some processing like:

- a1.example.com:2430
- a2.example.com:8280
- a3.example.com:4380
- a4.example.com:4280
- a5.example.com:3158
- a6.example.com:8238

I have looked into configuring squid proxy as transparent proxy. But how should I enforce every outgoing connection (with different destination ports ) to redirect to localhost proxy.